# What is the Implementation of: + (instancetype)array;

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I'm curious to know what the actual implementation of the class method `+ (instancetype)array` that is declared in `NSArray.h` would look like:

**NSArray.h**

```
+ (instancetype)array;
```

**NSArray.m**

```
+ (instancetype)array {
    // What goes here?
}
```

Comment: If you explain why you need to know, you may get better answers.

Comment: Digging around in [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/) may turn up something.

Comment: Curiosity was the primary reason, honestly.  That being said, I wanted to implement something similar in one of my custom classes, and wanted to do it correctly.  `return [[self alloc] init];` seemed almost too simple, so I thought I would ask more experienced devs. :)  Thanks for the link too; didn't know about that resource!

Comment: It would be `return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];` in non-ARC codebases, but yes, still ridiculously simple.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely:

```
+ (instancetype)array {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

But it's possible it may do other things, or call other initializers.

I'm not sure if it does anything special because it's a toll-free bridged class.

Comment: Of course this assume ARC. Under MRC there would also be a call to `autorelease`.

Comment: So, related question: Did this change after the advent of `ARC`?  IIRC, calling `[NSArray array]` was a way to get an autoreleased version of `NSArray`.

Comment: Thanks, @rmaddy; you answered before I even had a chance to ask. :)

Comment: I don't think Foundation is compiled with ARC. (Witness the use of `assign` semantics for delegate properties.)

Comment: Heh, good point about toll-free bridging. Still, seems likely that those kinds of implementation details would be encapsulated in the `init...` methods rather than exposed in all of the factory methods.

Comment: I suspect it will be slightly more than just this, because the instance it returns is actually an undocumented subclass (NSArray is a class-cluster)